# Vb6- Move focus to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vb6, powerpoint, vba

The VB6 exe program is launched from an Excel add-in and is supposed to move the focus to an open PowerPoint presentation that should become the visible window.

```
With PPApp.ActiveWindow
    .ViewType = View
End With
```

While in IDE mode **the focus moves properly and PowerPoint is the visible window**. But in the compiled form (the exe file) the PowerPoint icon in the taskbar blinks but PowerPoint is not the active visible window

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `PPApp.Activate` after setting the view type.